# Django returns 'TemplateDoesNotExist' when using Crispy Forms

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-crispy-forms

Using Crispy Forms with Django, I can only get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error when using any feature of Crispy Forms.

As I'm new to Crispy Forms (which seems to be universally recommended for *quickly* making forms look better), I have followed the instructions at https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html and as far as I know, the installation is correct (installed using `pip` and changes in `settings.py`). I am running this in a virtual environment (the `.venv` folder referred to below) on a Windows machine.

I have even created a new project specifically to look at this, with absolutely minimal content, and the same problem persists. The project is called 'stuff' and the single app in it 'other'.

**settings.py**

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'other',
    'bootstrap4'
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

...
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Mine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mine

class MineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mine
        fields = ('name','email')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *

def idx(request):
    tform = MineForm()

    return render(request,'test.html',{'aform': tform})
```

**test.html**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TestThing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ aform|crispy }}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**results of pip freeze**

```
asgiref==3.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
Django==4.1.7
django-bootstrap4==22.3
django-crispy-forms==2.0
soupsieve==2.4
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2022.7
```

**error reported on debug page**

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
bootstrap4/uni_form.html
```

***Template-loader postmortem***

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProjectDir\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\bootstrap4\uni_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProjectDir\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\bootstrap4\uni_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProjectDir\other\templates\bootstrap4\uni_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProjectDir\.venv\lib\site-packages\bootstrap4\templates\bootstrap4\uni_form.html (Source does not exist)
```

It looks to me like Crispy can't see the templates which should have been installed. Or perhaps there's something else I'm supposed to download or create?

I wanted to quickly tidy a form up in my Django project before moving on to more pressing matters, and hours later I still can't get Crispy Forms to function at all (it would have been quicker to sort this in other ways). It's clear I'm missing something, but what?

**Other Weird and Wonderful things I've tried**

Not all of these might be logical, but hey!

- deliberately putting the wrong string in `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK` -- this results in an error suggesting I need to use `bootstrap3`, `bootstrap4`, or `uni_form`. Although repeating this experiment keeps the error reported above (with the misspelling)
- removing the `django-bootstrap4` module and loading from CDN (no difference)
- creating a blank HTML file at the path shown for the template, which just fails to render the form
- using `{% crispy aform %}` - same result

Comment: The error at the bottom of the post tells you all the directories where it looked, and couldn't find, the template.  So what is _the actual location_ of the template?

Comment: @john Unfortunately what it's looking for is the `uni_form.html` file, which is part of the Crispy Forms system. Creating a blank file with that name in one of those paths gets rid of the error, and renders a page with no form.

All references I've found so far to Crispy Forms seem to suggest doing the pip install, installing in the project, and using the `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` tag at the top of the template, with the form piped through `crispy`.

There has been no suggestion of having to manually create a template file, or install one from elsewhere.

Comment: Does the problem still exist when you remove bootstrap4 `pip uninstall bootstrap4` and remove it from your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @Marco Unfortunately, it persists even when doing that (and obviously loading bootstrap manually)

Comment: Have you set "APP_DIRS" to True in TEMPLATE variable in settings.py? Try setting it to False. In my project it was set to False to prevent Django to look at the default locations in each app redundantly as all my templates and static file live at project level. BTW, I'm using bootstrap5 downloaded locally and not django's built in package. Anyway i had the same error and modifying back to False resolved my issue

Comment: After setting APP_DIRS to False, the template for the Django debug toolbar is not found. Error message: TemplateDoesNotExist - debug_toolbar/base.html

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As of django-crispy-forms 2.0 the template packs are now in separate packages.

You will need to `pip install crispy-bootstrap4` and add `crispy_bootstrap4` to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Thank you - that is exactly the solution. I've had another look, and can't see anything pointing in that direction on the Crispy Forms site (in fact it says "Since version 2.0, django-crispy-forms has built-in support for version 3 and 4 of the Bootstrap CSS framework").

Comment: You are a god! I've been searching 1h in the internet until I found you!

Comment: The erroneous text in the documentation was fixed on 24th March: https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/commit/443ebd208d0945b87e063c6d780e93ba599da17a

Answer (score 16):

if you need to use bootstrap4

1. pip install django-crispy-forms
2. pip install crispy-bootstrap4

inside settings.py in the main app add
`INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... 'crispy_forms', 'crispy_bootstrap4', ... ]`
and `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`

inside your_html.html file add
`{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` and you can use cripy_forms as you like

Answer (score 4):

1. Run this command:

   ```
   pip install django-crispy-forms
   ```
2. Go to settings.py and add this in the installed apps (don't forget the comma):

   ```
   "crispy_forms",
   "crispy_bootstrap4"
   ```
3. Add this after the installed apps (here there's no need for a comma):

   ```
   CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap4"
   CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
   ```
4. Go to the html page where you want to add the crispy form and add this in the head section:

   ```
   {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
   ```
5. Finally add this to the body section:

   ```
   {{form|crispy_field}}
   ```

Comment: Follow all above steps giving me this error:
 Invalid filter: 'crispy_field'

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and got solution. This is because you are using *django-crispy-forms==2.0* and your project is not compatible with this version. also this django-crispy-forms==2.0 not support **bootstrap4**.

**SOLUTION:**
*so install packages with below mention version:
(make sure python version > 3.7)*

- pip3 install Django==4.1.6
- pip3 install django-allauth==0.52.0
- pip3 install django-crispy-forms==1.14.0  # version <=1.70
- pip3 install django-embed-video

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to pip install django_crispy_forms==1.2
This will install the first version of crispy forms